# How can I receive a touch event?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'd like to receive a touch event.  Also I'd like some kind of coordinates indicating where the user touched the screen.

How can I receive a touch event in an iPhone app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the -touchesBegan, -touchesMoved, and -touchesEnded methods of the UIView class - you'll want to subclass that and override those methods. Each one gives you an NSSet of UITouch objects; unless you're dealing with multitouch, you can get the touch object by calling -anyObject on the set. Then, call -locationInView: with the view itself (or another view that you want the coordinates relative to).